# change axis color dimple

Tags: d3.js, dimple.js

I have a very simple line chart in dimple. I want to change the x and y axis colour to white.

```
var svg = dimple.newSvg(".line_chart_container", 400, 300),dataset;
var chart = new dimple.chart(svg, dataset);
var x = chart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Attempts");
//x.style ("fill","red")
var y = chart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Value");
y.showGridlines = true;
x.showGridlines = true;
var s = chart.addSeries(["Metric", "Value"], dimple.plot.bubble);
var lines = chart.addSeries("Metric", dimple.plot.line); 
lines.lineWeight = 2;
lines.lineMarkers = true;
chart.assignColor("Metric", "#30D630");
chart.draw();
s.shapes.style("opacity", function (d) {
return (d.yValue === 0 ? 0 : 0.8);
});
```

I've checked [dimple.axis documentation in GitHub](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#colors) but couldn't find any thing. There is a dimple.axis.colors attribute, but it changes the color of the data and not the axis. Does dimple even support this?

I've also tried to add style attribute(like in D3):

```
x.style ("fill","red")
```

but caught an error: Uncaught TypeError: x.style is not a function

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x` is not a d3 selection, it is a [dimple.axis](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis). You can access the inner d3 selection with the `shapes` property (which is standard for any dimple object). There is an example of that [here](https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.axis#shapes).

Depending on if you want to change the line color, text color, or everything, you would do

```
x.shapes.selectAll("*").style("fill", "white")
```

where * could also be "text" or "line". 
One note : the individual tick marks are `<line>` nodes, and to change their color you need to use 'stroke', not 'fill'.
Also, the actual axis line itself is not a `<line>` element, it's a `<path>` element. So to change that color would be :

```
x.shapes.select("path.dimple-custom-axis-line").style("stroke", "white");
```

You can also just manually write a css rule to override the style for a chart :

```
g.dimple-axis > g.tick > line, g.dimple-axis path.dimple-custom-axis-line {
  stroke:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For X-axis

```
d3.selectAll("path.domain")[0][0].style.stroke = "red";
```

For Y-axis

```
d3.selectAll("path.domain")[0][1].style.stroke = "yellow";
```